How to automatically subset matrix to get matching dimensions between matrices
I have two matrices that have different dimensions. I want to subset one of them so that the dimensions are the same. The two matrices are the VOO and VTI matrices using quantmod getSymbol().
VOO is 3415x6 and VTI is 4434x6. For them two have matching dimensions, I'd have to subset VTI to be VTI[929:4434,]. I want to do this for multiple ETFS and it will be tedious to find each number to subset individually.
I made a function which can tell me how many rows bigger one matrix is than the other but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this like a function already built in.
This is my code.
dim(VOO)
dim(VTI)
4434 - 3415
cor(VTI[929:4343, ], VOO)

Testing using function
matrix.subset <- function(x, y) {
  if (dim(x)[1] > dim(y)[1]) {
    cat("x", ">", "y", " : ", as.numeric(dim(x)[1] - dim(y)[1]))
  }
  if (dim(y)[1] > dim(x)[1]) {
    cat("y", ">", "x", " : ", as.numeric(dim(y)[1] - dim(x)[1]))
  }
}
matrix.subset(VOO, VTI)

Output:
y > x  :  928


Just FYI, in cat you don't have to go one character at a time. You and do cat("x > y : ", ...)

If VOO and VTI are the result of calling quantmod::getSymbols then they are xts objects, not just matrices.  Convert them to zoo, use merge.zoo with the indicated arguments and then optionally convert back to xts. This will return the objects such that only the times in both are returned.  With this code syms can have more than 2 symbols if desired.  See ?merge.zoo
library(quantmod)

syms <- c("VOO", "VTI")
getSymbols(syms)

L <- mget(syms)
L2 <- L |>
  lapply(as.zoo) |>
  do.call(\(...) merge(..., retclass = "list", all = FALSE), args = _) |>
  lapply(as.xts)

# check

sapply(L, dim)
##       VOO  VTI
## [1,] 3415 4343
## [2,]    6    6

sapply(L2, dim)
##       VOO  VTI
## [1,] 3415 3415
## [2,]    6    6


Thanks for the response. Your code was able to clear this up for me!

I would use the tail function, which takes the last n rows of a matrix or data frame (or last n values of a vector), and probably write the function like this:
matrix_subset = function(m_list) {
  min_rows = min(sapply(m_list, nrow))
  lapply(m_list, tail, n = min_rows)
}

This function takes a list of matrices input, finds the one with the fewest n rows, and truncates them all to the bottom n rows. (It doesn't do anything to columns.) It then returns the result in a list. You can use it on a list of 2 matrices, or on more.
mm = list(
  big = matrix(1:16, ncol = 2),
  small = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2),
  medium = matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
)
matrix_subset(mm)
# $big
#      [,1] [,2]
# [7,]    7   15
# [8,]    8   16
# 
# $small
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# $medium
#      [,1] [,2]
# [4,]    4    9
# [5,]    5   10


Got it, your function helped me make this more efficient. Thanks!
